# Center middle of 3 images, left and right images align to middle image

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to have the middle of 3 images centered horizontally, then have the left image align to the left of the middle image, and the right image align to the right of the middle image?

https://jsfiddle.net/0wk84qaf/

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award1-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
        <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award3-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
        <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award2-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see, currently, the whole div is centered, but the middle image is slightly off-center, whereas I'd like it to be bang in the middle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning. Center the middle image in the parent, and absolutely position the other elements to either side of that parent.

```css
.images {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.images img:first-child,
.images img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.images img:first-child {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%,-50%);
}

.images img:last-child {
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award1-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
    <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award3-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
    <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award2-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flex, it's really good for things like this. The output you may have to tweak yourself but what you requested is there.

Take a look at this [link to view more on flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.img-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-holder .img {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.img-holder img {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div class="img-holder">

<div class="img">
  <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award1-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
</div>

<div class="img img-smaller">
  <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award3-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
</div>

<div class="img">
  <img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award2-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make your img tags have width of 33.3%

```html
<div style="text-align:center;"><div style="display:inline-block;
%"><img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award1-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%" /><img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award3-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%" /><img src="http://rubyandgrace.cdudigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/award2-2.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;width:33.3%" /></div></div>
```